# Is there a way to assign to a variable it value from the previous period specific to the same observation in R?

Tags: r, database, time-series, panel, panel-data

I have a panel data like this :

```
year      ID        S(t)    

2008      N987      S1234     
2009      N987      S8875     
2010      N987      S7465     

2008      E867      F8402     
2009      E867      S1234     
2010      E867      R9879     
2011      E867      Q8687     
2012      E867      F8687     
2013      E867      J8687
```

I want,

```
year      ID        S(t)    S(t-1)

2008      N987      S1234     0
2009      N987      S8875     S1234
2010      N987      S7465     S8875

2008      E867      F8402     0
2009      E867      S1234     F8402
2010      E867      R9879     S1234
2011      E867      Q8687     R9879
2012      E867      F8687     Q8687
2013      E867      J8687     F8687
```

But I have 304429 different ID's, and the Panel is not ordered by year and id.

Can someone please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Using `dplyr` : `df %>% arrange(ID, year) %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(lag_st = lag(st, default = 0))`

Comment: @RonakShah When using it I have a message error: error in mutate_impl(.data,dots): Expecting a single string value:[type=double; extent=1].

Comment: Add first few rows of your data using `dput` i.e if your dataframe is called `df` do `dput(head(df))` and edit your post. In `lag` make sure that you are using the column name present in your data.

Comment: @RonakShah now I have another message error: lag_st must be length 10 (the groupe size) or one, not 304429  (which is the numer of ids)